# php based application to make request to grails plugin project

Tags: web-services, grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I have grails plugin project, i need to convert it to webservice, so that my php code can make a request to newly created webservice.

In short, i need to expose my grails plugin project, so that my php based application can make request to that.

Is there any support to make a call from my php based application to grails plugin project.

Any idea is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: how would you know where your plugin is hosted? or are you talking about private plugin on your project only?

Comment: It is a custom plugin project created by me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugins can be developed and tested standalone, but in order to use them it has to be installed in a host application.

AFAIU, you have a custom plugin which has some XYZ service which you want to expose as a webservice. In order to do so, you have to follow these steps:

- Create a grails app. (Not a plugin)
- Install your plugin in the app. (by defining the plugin in `BuildConfig.groovy` of the app)
- One way to expose the service as a RESTful webservice is to follow @Saurabh's approach.
- Alternative way is to expose the service class in plugin using [cxf plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/cxf) inside your plugin. (Untested, but you can try if you can achieve what you need without using REST url mappings).

Motive is to create a `deployable` component (`war`, `ear`, `jar`) which could `produce/expose` your custom service as a webservice. You can achieve the same from a grails application than a grails plugin which is nothing but a packaged `zip` archive.

Answer (score 0):

You can try grails web services, for example; REST can be used and you can call your grails application through a url and can pass parameter to it through POST, GET and handle them on grails controller

you can call a URL and handle the url paramters on the URL mapping:

for example if you call your grails app through some URL: product/ then you will be able to handle the request on your grails app as:

```
"/product/$id"(controller: "product", parseRequest: true) {
            action = [GET: "show", PUT: "update", DELETE: "delete", POST: "save"]
```

and in your controller you can parse the request like:

```
if( request.method == "GET" ){
        println( "GET REQUEST RECEIVED" )
            <......Some Code........>
        render resultList as JSON
    }else if( request.method == "POST" ){
        println( "POST REQUEST RECEIVED" )
            <......Some Code........>
        render resultList as JSON
    }
        }
```

request and reponse can be handled in xml or JSON format, have a look at: http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/guide/webServices.html#REST

Comment: Can you please package the plugin as a `war` and deploy it so that I can use this sample REST service?